Return entries within last 24 hours of a specific date time in SQL
I have a dataset which contains two different datetimes - datetime1 and datetime2.
I would like to return all the entries where the datetime2 has occurred in the last 24 hours of datetime1.
I tried this query below but gives me all the entries.
WHERE datetime2 <= DATEADD(HOUR, 24, datetime1)

Is there a function that will return the entries with datetime2 that occurred in the past 24 hours of datetime1?

That WHERE clause looks correct. Show use some example data.

I think you have it the other way around - you select all entries which are datetime2-wise younger then datetime1 + 24 hours and I think you want it the other way around, do not you?

Here are some examples of your WHERE clause working on sql-server https://dbfiddle.uk/8G-m5Kh5

I formulate it like where datetime2 >= DATEADD(HOUR , -24 , datetime1) and datetime2 <= datetime1, i.e. datetime2 is bigger or equal datetime1 minus 24 hours and at the same time datetime2 is not after datetime1.

@Michal yeah that's what it seemed like to me as well (could do the same with a between criteria as well).

Which dbms are you using? (datediff is a non-standard SQL function.)

Try this:
WHERE datetime2 BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -24, datetime1) AND datetime1


where datetime2 >= DATEADD(HOUR , -24 , datetime1) and datetime2 <= datetime1
This query works! Thank you
